# How to implement logging in a console app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Right now I put `console.log(something)` where I want to see what's happening in those places where I put it. When I see it's fine, I remove it.

How do I better implement logging functionality which I can easily turn on/off, e.g. with a start command line parameter `node app.js debug=true`?

Comment: Did you try to research this before asking your question?  A Google Search for "logging in nodejs" yields [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/) as the first search result, which contains a number of relevant strategies.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=node.js+log+library&oq=node.js+log+library&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [turns](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/) [up](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) [interesting](https://www.loggly.com/blog/node-js-libraries-make-sophisticated-logging-simpler/) [results](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-node-js-logging-winston-bunyan/)

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this is a question for an ecosystem as rich as nodejs.

Comment: have you tried using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)?

Comment: @RitikSaxena: Winston is mentioned in the article I linked.

Comment: I initially wanted to implement basic logging functionality from scratch so my bad I didn't guess to find an existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

somewhere in your code:

```
const debug = true
```

then:

```
    if(debug){
      console.log(yourvar)
    }
```

or like someone suggested:

```
function debugMe(debug, yourvar){
  if(debug){
    console.log(yourvar)
  }
}
```

wrap it in a function

Comment: Wrap this in a function. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using different logging levels. Ideally the log statements that you delete after development can be assigned to DEBUG level. So they will output only when the app is running in debug mode.

Most 3rd party loggers support this. You can check out [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest you could do is use [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs) or any similar node packages

Add this code as a logger-service and wrap it in a function

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
});
```

Require this logger service's function and log using any of the below formats.

```
logger.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: 'Hello distributed log files!'
});

logger.info('Hello again distributed logs');
```

Hope this helps.